# Migrating a question deleted a comment

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions

I migrated [a question from Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9812/82) over [to Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30514/3512).

When it got there, it had lost [the last comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9812/is-marliyn-vos-savant-correct-about-the-2-3-odds-in-her-version-of-the-monty-hal?noredirect=1#comment39801_9812). I’m confident that the comment wasn’t deleted by a moderator on Stats since it was gone *immediately* after the question arrived on that site.

This looks like a bug, no?

Comment: Since this is `[status-bydesign]`, you _can_ make it into a `[feature-request]`--> "Don't auto delete comments longer than X chars"

Comment: @Manish Not sure it’s worth it … I’m still thinking ;)

Comment: Just observed this as well, I guess the algorithm isn't appropriate for every case. In my case I had left a comment on a post on a site meta containing a related question on MSE. [Then the post was migrated to MSE and the comment was deleted](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/comment-migration), although it should not have been. Maybe this *should* be a [tag:bug]?

Comment: Here is a related feature request: [Don't automatically delete comments with useful content on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279510).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an intended feature, any comment linking to the target site gets removed, as it likely is something along the lines

> This question belongs on site X

and is not necessary anymore after migration. In this case the comment was …

> @user1873 This is not a question of “belief” or “opinion”. I do see the supposed ambiguity, but I also know that the two interpretations collapse into the same. People who think that the two alternative interpretations yield different results simply lack a piece of knowledge (in particular, they discard conditional probabilities, or they confuse p(A|B) and p(B|A)). All people who understand Bayes see that the two alternatives will yield the same result. These comments are inadequate to explain this. Why don’t you repost the question on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://example.com)?

… where the comment deletion trigger (on the target site) is a link to the target site in the comment itself.

Comment: Arrgh. Bad heuristic.

Comment: *Any* link to the target site? Even if linked to a specific question? (Like: a possible duplicate on the target site?)

Comment: @Arjan You'll have to ask someone that works for SE for the specifics