# Why was only one of these comments deleted upon migration?

Tags: bug, migrated-questions, deleted-comments

Today, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100208/issues-with-tempdb-mdf-file-ever-increasing?noredirect=1) was migrated from the main site to [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/issues-with-tempdb-mdf-file-ever-increasing). Before migration, it had two comments; one simple one about being better suited, and a more elaborate one which *happened* to link to a *specific* answer on dba.se. (I've included screenshots for those < 10K in case it gets deleted on the source site.)

> [image: comments on question BEFORE migration]

---

When the question was migrated, only the top comment remained (which I promptly deleted):

> [image: comments on question AFTER migration]

---

I'm pretty sure this is not how this is *supposed* to work. Either only the first should have been deleted, or at worst, they both should have been deleted. But I don't know exactly what the algorithm is or how these auto-delete decisions are made. In this case, it back-fired - deleting a useful (IMHO) comment, and leaving behind the redundant one.

Comment: Probably because the actual comment uses `[dba.se]`, which the check might not look for since it's not actually a link in the comment body.

Comment: This is what happened: First comment was provided as `This question would be better suited for [dba.se]`, which was auto-formatted to read `This question would be better suited for [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com)`. The second comment uses an explicit `dba.stackexchange.com` address, [which caused the deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136199/168244). Bad heuristic indeed, since some constructive comments *should* remain across migration (for example, suggested duplicates/related posts).

Comment: Ok, thanks folks, however I still think this isn't functioning correctly. I am fully aware of the intended functionality, why and how it is supposed to work, etc. but I think (1) the deletion script should detect the shorthand versions of URLs too, and (2) it should not detect full URLs with additional specifics. IMHO.

Answer (score 12):

This is what happened:

1. First comment was provided as

   ```
   This question would be better suited for [dba.se]
   ```

   which was [auto-formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to read

   ```
   This question would be better suited for
   [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com)
   ```
2. The second comment uses an *explicit* `dba.stackexchange.com` address, [which caused the deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136199/168244) (implicit site suggestions that match the target are also deleted).

Indeed a bad heuristic, since some constructive comments should remain across migration, IMO (for example, suggested duplicates/related posts on the target site).