# VTC comment exists after migration when it shouldn't

Tags: bug, comments, vote-to-close, migration

Based on the response to [Migrating a question deleted a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136199/migrating-a-question-deleted-a-comment/136200#136200), comments regarding migration should be removed after migrating.

The following post contains a situation where the comment was not removed, thus required a flag as "*no longer needed*".

As of the time of this post, the example can be found here: [Is it a good practice to add code on an existing class with thousands of lines when adding a new feature in a legacy Java project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398799/is-it-a-good-practice-to-add-code-on-an-existing-class-with-thousands-of-lines-w)

I tagged *bug* due to the intended behavior mentioned in the first linked post.

Comment: That's just a custom comment that happens to not match the regex pattern that auto-deletes such comments. Sometimes that happens. We can't automatically catch everything.

Comment: Also, flagging the comment as no longer needed will most likely result in deletion quick enough. Well anyways the entire Q appears deleted now, so that solved itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen quite a bit, especially when people write up custom comments indicating a question is a duplicate. What happens is the regex used to clean up the comments after a closure doesn't pick up on some comments and thus they get left. Generally, any of the auto-generated comments get picked up in my experience and the issue is more when a user writes their own.

Generally, I would expect the regex for this is written in such a way that minimises incorrect deletion of comments, so it certainly won't be able to pick up everything.

Doing what you did and flagging as No Longer Needed is the correct option for these types of comments.